# How to install MySQLdb within my own setup.py?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I current have a setup.py file for an application I've written. Using setuptools I've easily been able to install pip-available requirements as such:

```
install_requires = [
    'argparse',
    'multiprocessing',
    'requests',
    'numpy',
    'termcolor',
    'prettytable'
]
```

The problem is that I also need to install MySQLdb, which is not installed via pip. When setting up locally, I had to download the tarball, uncompress, install, symlink, etc... To put it short, it was a PITA.

Is there anyway to automate this within my `setup.py` file? Rather than downloading the tarball and including it as a package? Even then, how would I run a `setup.py` within my own `setup.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually install MySQLdb via pip, but the package is named `MySQL-python`.

Now, your users will still need the package's C dependencies installed (`libmysqlclient`), but this is easily installed with a package manager. It would also be reasonably easy to provide a non-`setup.py` install script (e.g. a `bash` script) that installs the appropriate system dependencies (`libmysqlclient`) and calls your `setup.py`:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev  # Improve me! Check the platform first
python setup.py install
```

Just don't try to do too much in your `setup.py`. No one expects a `setup.py` script to install system packages, so you should refrain from doing that in yours.

---

Now, if requiring users to install a system package is too much (if they don't have root access, it can be), you should use a pure-Python MySQL client instead.

One such client is [`pymysql`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), which of course can be installed via pip.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but unfortunately the people using this script are heavily divided between Mac OSX and Linux users, and installation of MySQLdb is very different between the two OS's. I might just provide a short how-to along with the script as to how install it, platform specific.

Comment: @carbon_ghost What differs is the installation of `libmysqlclient` *not* that of `MySQLdb`. Definitely, document how to install the library, but have the `setup.py` pull down MySQLdb as a dependency. Now, **I would heavily recommend looking into `pymysql`**. It's a drop-in and portable replacement for MySQLdb, and it seems to be exactly what you're looking for here.